# Combine results of multiple sql queries in multiple columns all alone

Tags: sql, plsql, informix

I have multiple queries, which produces just a count (one cell only) in one column. I need to combine those columns.

Suppose the queries are:

```
select count (*) from address where city = NULL as citycount;
select count (*)  from address where countrycode = 4 as countrycount;
select count (*) from address;
```

Above queries will return the results:

```
citycount

40

countrycount

50

count(*)

400045
```

I want to combine above queries in such a manner so that result will be:

```
 citycount countrycount  count(*)

    40        50          400045
```

This means the columns will get combined . I have more than 30 queries.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i wonder how `city=null` gets you a result.

Comment: Are you working on Oracle (which supports PL/SQL) or Informix (which does not support Oracle's PL/SQL)?  The `= NULL` notation is not accepted by Informix (or standard SQL, AFAIK), so you should probably be tagging the question with Oracle (as hinted in the PL/SQL tag description) and probably not with Informix unless you explain that you need a bilingual solution (in which case, you won't be using `= NULL`).

Comment: The expression `COUNT(*) - COUNT(city)` should give you the number of null cities (`COUNT(column_name)` counts the number of non-null values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use SUM with CASE Expression:**

```
 select 
    sum(case when city = NULL then 1 else 0 end ) as citycount,
    sum(case when countrycode=4 then 1 else 0 end ) as countrycount,
    count(*) as countt
    from address
```

Comment: This is based on users query,he might have set ansi nulls :)

Comment: Is that Oracle/plsql or Informix behavior?

Comment: @jarlh: It is not Informix behaviour.  Using `= NULL` yields the Informix generic error `-201: A syntax error has occurred`.  Using `IS NULL` instead yields two nulls and a 0 when the table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
(select count (*) from address where city IS NULL) as citycount,
(select count (*) from address where countrycode = 4) as countrycount,
count(*)
from address
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad,I have tried the same as well  it is working fine for 2-3 queries . But not for 20-30 queries. Can we have the optimized way

Comment: @app: This is more or less what is going to be necessary.  If your aggregates have different filter conditions, then you'll need different expressions along the lines here to calculate them.  Or you can use the CASE formulation in another answer.  Reviewing the query plans would tell you which is the better performing variant — it will depend on the optimizer (and making sure you have appropriate indexes, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this... hope it helps

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Cnt INT NOT NULL,
DescTableName VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #TEST (Cnt, DescTableName)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt, 'citycount' AS DescTableName FROM dbo.[Subscriptions] 

INSERT INTO #TEST (Cnt, DescTableName)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt, 'countrycount' AS DescTableName FROM dbo.ReportSchedule

INSERT INTO #TEST (Cnt, DescTableName)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt, 'address' AS DescTableName FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs 

SELECT * FROM #TEST

DROP TABLE #TEST
```

Comment: This will give three rows in the `#TEST` table, won't it?  Not one row with three values.  Your second and third operations should be UPDATE operations, not INSERT operations.